# $\sum_{0\leqslant y \leqslant z \leqslant k \leqslant n} (\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{z}\binom{n-k-z}{y})$ =?

Tags: summation, combinations, binomial-theorem, multinomial-coefficients

**Evaluate**

$$\sum_{0\leqslant y \leqslant z \leqslant 
k \leqslant n} (\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{z}\binom{n-k-z}{y})$$

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Are we assuming $k+z+y\leq n$? Or equivalently, that all "invalid" binomial coefficients evaluate to $0$?

Comment: It's wonderful that you've learned how to post latex code, but perhaps you could also learn to give context and politely ask for help.

Comment: I'm not getting what to do...?

Comment: In that case, there are two things you can almost always try: Simplify the problem, and / or calculate the actual value for small cases. Remove one of the binomial coefficients, calculate the value for $n=1,2,3$, that sort of stuff. Also, since these are binomial coefficients, there is likely some combinatorial interpretation (which, again, might be easier to spot if you remove a coefficient or two from the term).